# 3D manipulator is in wrong position

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

my 3D manipulator is always in the wrong position. I have tried everything to make it work, yet nothing has. I have relaunched it, and everything I can think of.

[image]

I simply cannot work like this. Please help.

Answer (score 8):

This is happening for one of several reasons, most likely because you moved the mesh while in edit mode changing the origin point (the little orange dot where the widget is).

Looking at the image, your pivot point is most likely already on the default *Bounding Box Center* and what you want is to have the widget on the object. So to fix, select the object in *Object mode* and set the object origin back to the object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and choose *Origin to Geometry*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In that screen shot you have the 3D Pivot point set to `Active element` The placement of the manipulator when only one object is selected, (with the pivot point set to Active element) is the Object *Origin*.

To fix that just select that object and any other that has the origin in the wrong spot; then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and select `Origin to Geometry`